# a cell containing the same value of another cell in column

Tags: excel-2007

```
P12100600006    P12100100000    P12100600000    121006
P12100600006    P12100100000    P12100600000    121006
M12200100012    P12100400000    P12110100001    121101
P12200700000    P12100400000    P12100600000    121006
M12200100012    P12100400000    P12110200016    121102
M12200100012    P12100500000    P12100100000    121001
M12200100012    P12100600000    P12100500000    121005
P12200700000    P12200100000    P12200700000    122007
P12200700000    P12200100000    P12200700000    122007
P12200700000    P12200100000    P12200700000    122007
P12200700000    P12200100000    P12200700000    122007
P12200700000    P12200100000    P12200700000    122007
P12200700000    P12200100000    P12200700000    122007
P12200700000    P12200100000    P12200700000    122007
M12200100012    P12200100000    P12200600000    122006
P12200100001    P12200200000    P12200400004    122004
R12200100000    P12200400000    P12205200000    122052
R12200100000    P12200400000    P12205200000    122052
R12200100000    P12200400000    P12205200000    122052
P12200500000    P12200400000    P12200700000    122007
P12200100000    P12200700000    P12200100000    122001
```

In the above given data I want if A1 contains the value in D1 respectively like A2 contains D2 and so on. In excel for example in last row column A is P12200100000 having the value of D columns whose value is 122001

otherwise find if first 7 element of column A and Column C are same

Comment: thank you for the formatting, but there is still no real question here.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: your question is only unclear for me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(FIND(D1,A1),LEFT(A1,7)=LEFT(C1,7))
```

copied down should give a numeric result if in the same row (starting at 1) the value in ColumnA contains the value in ColumnD. Otherwise, if the first seven characters of ColumnA are the same as the first seven characters of ColumnC of the same row the result should be TRUE. If neither of these the result should be FALSE.

But as with others, I am not certain whether this is your requirement, only that is how I think it can be interpreted.